# Loop through array and add data

Tags: node.js, arrays

I have an array called **"content"**. In this array is the "asin-id" (It's a kind of product ID). I'm trying to loop through the content array and get from the asin-id the specific product so I can add the product to the array and save the new content-array in the db.

Something is wrong. I don't know how to do it.

**Expected result:**

```
content: [{ asin: "asin-ID", product: product }, ...]
```

**What I tried:**

```js
exports.createBlogPost = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const content = req.body.content

        content.map(async (element) => {
            const asin = element.asin
            const product = await Product.findOne({ asin: asin })
            element.product = product
            return element
        })

        console.log(content)
    

        const post = new BlogPost({
            postTitle: req.body.postTitle,
            postQuery: req.body.postQuery,
            content: content,
            mainImage: req.file
        })
        console.log("Saved: " + post)
        await post.save()

        if(post) {
            return res.status(200).json({
                success: true,
                message: 'Saved blog post successfully',
                post: post
            })
        }
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: "Something is wrong" isn't sufficient for explaining your error... You should be as specific as possible, especially pertaining to the actual error occurring, so that we can help.

Comment: The problem is I don‘t get the product in the content array.

Comment: I see. You're not actually getting an error... The values just aren't being populated as expected. I think I see the issue. I posted an answer that should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may be simply that you're using `map` without assigning the result to a variable. Try replacing your code with something similar to the following:

```
let updatedContent = content.map(async (element) => {
        const asin = element.asin
        const product = await Product.findOne({ asin: asin })
        element.product = product
        return element
 })

 console.log(updatedContent)
```